# Search MySql db with multiple "WHERE IN" and "OR" not working

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, where-clause

Suppose I have a table like this:

[image]

Suppose my user inputs that he wants to see all records where gender is male AND eyecolor = grey.

I already have the following SQL for that:

```
SELECT User, question, answer FROM [Table] WHERE User IN (
    SELECT User FROM [table] WHERE (question, answer) IN (
        ('gender', 'male'),
        ('eyecolor', 'grey')
    )
)
GROUP BY User
HAVING count(distinct question, answer) = 2)
```

However, what if my user wants to see all records for `(gender = male OR gender = female) AND eyecolor = grey` ? How would I format the above sql query to get it to be able to find that?

(Keep in mind, this is a searchform, so eyecolor and gender are only a few fields used for searching; I need to be able to search with and/or combo's)

I'm thinking the only way I can get this to work is something like:

```
SELECT User
FROM [table]
WHERE (gender = male OR gender = female) AND eyecolor = blue
```

And my php would have to build the query so that if the user enters more fields, the query expands with more `WHERE`'s etc.?

I have been searching all over but have not been able to get it to work.. Admittedly I'm not the world's greatest with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e112/1/0

```
select * 
from   stuff
where  ID in (   
       select ID
       from   stuff
       where  (question='gender' and answer in ('male','female')) or 
              (question='eyecolor' and answer='grey') 
       group by ID
       having count(ID)=2 
      )
```

where `2` is the number of conditions in the nested `where` statement.  If you run that nested select on its own, it will give you just a distinct list of ID's that fit the conditions.  The outer statement allows the query to return all records for the ID's that fit those conditions.

*i edited this because.... i was wrong before*

---

k... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f526/1/0

```
select  *
from   stuff
where  (question='gender'   and answer in ('male','female')) or 
       (question='eyecolor' and answer='grey')  or 
       (question='city'     and answer in ('madrid','amsterdam'))
```

for this query, we return one row that matches any of those conditions for any ID.  only ID's that satisfy at least one of those conditions will appear in the results.

```
select ID, count(*) as matches
from   stuff
where  (question='gender'   and answer in ('male','female')) or 
       (question='eyecolor' and answer='grey')  or 
       (question='city'     and answer in ('madrid','amsterdam')) 
group  by ID;
```

then we add the group by, so we can see how many rows are returned for each user and how many conditions they met (`count(*)`).

```
select ID
from   stuff
where  (question='gender'   and answer in ('male','female')) or 
       (question='eyecolor' and answer='grey')  or 
       (question='city'     and answer in ('madrid','amsterdam')) 
group  by ID
having count(ID)=3;
```

the `having count(ID)=3;` is what makes this query work.  we only want ID's that had 3 rows returned because we have 3 conditions.

**and**.... we can't use `and` because no row in that table will ever meet more than one of those conditions at a single time.  `question` cannot be gender, eyecolor and city all at the same time.  it has to do with your table layout.  city will never be both madrid *and* amsterdam at the same time.... `and` will give us nothing.  so... by using the `having` and an `or`... we can do stuff that's happy...?

---

and to go on a tangent.... if your table looked like this:

```
ID      gender      eyecolor       city         
---------------------------------------------
100     male        blue           madrid
200     female      grey           amsterdam
300     male        brown          somewhere
```

you would use `and` because....

```
select  * 
from    table 
where   gender in ('male','female') and
        city in ('madrid','amsterdam') and 
        eyecolor = 'grey'
```

but your table is a special one and didn't want to go that way because you really shouldn't have a column for every question... what if they change or what if you add 20?  that'd be hard to maintain.

---

and....

```
select ID
from   stuff
where  question in ('gender','eyecolor','city')   and 
       answer in ('male','female','grey','madrid','amsterdam') 
group  by ID
having count(ID)=3;
```

does also work but i would really be cautious with that because.. the questions and answers should stay together and be explicit because.... what if it was a dating service?  and `male` could be an answer for a person's own gender or the gender they want to date and by doing `question='gender' and answer in ('male','female')` you are specifying exactly what you mean and not assuming that certain information is only a valid answer for one question.

Comment: I'm trying my best to get my head around this but can't get it to work.. so i have a userform in which a user enters: a record can be gender = 'male|female' and city 'madrid|amsterdam' and eyecolor='grey'. so, in other words: the db should return only id's which have eyecolor = grey and city either madrid or amsterdam and gender = male or female.i've tried both answers but could not get this to work! Your answer (gloomy) has OR while i need AND (i think)

Comment: k... hold on.  you wand all males and females who have grey eyes and now live in madrid or amsterdam, right?  (i have grey eyes but i dont live anywhere fun)

Comment: :-)  yes, i mean only records to be returned would then be:  (either males or females) with grey eyes who live (either in Madrid or Spain)

Comment: Yes!! this seems to be working! i opt for option 3 (having count>3). i have to go now but tomorrow eve i will try and implement your answer fully. Thank you kindly for your clear and well documented answer! As said, i will be back tomorrow and will let you know. I feel a big large YES (approval) comming your way ;-) THANKS!

Comment: i wrote that wrong.  `>3`... i changed it.  it should be `=3`.... sorry... it was `>=3` but that's unnecessary and i removed the wrong symbol for a second...

Comment: Right! i use php to build the sql statement you gave me and it seems to work fine now. However, i'm a bit worried about the length of the sql statement it generates. it's using your sql statement, the one with having count(ID)=3; in it. Will i get in trouble when i build a query with 50+ questions with some of 'em having 15-20 where-in answers? I supposed it would be too lengthy? Or is it fine or do i need to do something else? I thought i read something a while back about raising usable memory for sql through a command but i'm not sure it it's needed and how...

Comment: Besides, for only one 'where in' it needs to be >=1 otherwise my query only returns one ID..

Comment: i think i understand that question........ the `having count(*)=` needs to be set to the number of conditions you're trying to match for.  just eyecolor, set it to 1.  eyecolor and gender, set it to 2.  eyecolor, gender and city, set it to 3.  if you have fifty conditions, set it to 50.

Comment: Yep, noticed that :-)  What do you think about the length of the sql statement i wrote about 3 answers ago? can i get in trouble you think? I'm very happy with the results so far, many thanks!

Comment: oh, um... yeah, I can't think of another way to do it... you can look at the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html) for where clause optimization (I didn't use any unnesccary parenthases, btw)... but if you have 50 conditions, you have 50 conditions... you are going to have to put them all in somewhere eventually to get the correct results back.  i found [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11795453/623952) but it doesn't say too much.